# X-form and cross-form rudders in underwater control

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, marine-engineering, naval-engineering, submarines

What are the advantages of using X-form rudders in comparison to cross-form rudders?

Why do some submarines, torpedos and underwater autonomous vehicles use X-stern control?

X-stern:

[image: X-stern picture]

Cross-form:

[image: Cross-form]

Comment: related, on aviation.SE: [How do X-shaped control surfaces work?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24542/how-do-x-shaped-control-surfaces-work?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

People, people people (by which I mean the unreferenced other answers at this time) !  look it up!   Here is info from a [Chinese research paper](http://www.clausiuspress.com/conferences/ACSS/ICCSC%202017/BSES270.pdf):

> . Compared with the cross rudder, X-form rudder has the following
>   advantages:  Firstly, X-form rudder has the higher rudder efficiency
>   and its manipulate surface area is smaller about 10% than cross
>   rudder, so that submarine could avoid the collision problem when it is
>   landing. Secondly, X-form rudder reduces the serious consequences by
>   rudder-blocked and improves the security and the underwater dynamic
>   unsinkability. Besides, X-form rudder reduces the heeling moment,
>   weight and stern heaviness when cross-rudder submarine turning, and
>   having an advantage 13 2017 3rd International Conference on
>   Computational Systems and Communications (ICCSC 2017) Published by CSP
>   © 2017 the Authors to sail steadily when it is attacked. Finally,
>   X-form rudder reduces interaction between propeller and rudder, and
>   reduces the noise[4].

And a page I found quotes the following from a [Google Book reference](https://books.google.com/books?id=cN4cdjU5KTcC&pg=PA184&lpg=PA184&dq=x%20submarine%20rudder%20configuration&source=web&ots=8lC7YEEB3F&sig=EiS6D3LjGjEtixvulRvY7p5K3fo#v=onepage&q=x%20submarine%20rudder%20configuration&f=false),

> Most modern military submarines have a hull form that at least
>   approximates an axisymmetric body of revolution. Most of these have
>   four control surfaces at the stern for steering the vessel, that is,
>   for making it turn left or right--the rudder--or rise or dive--diving
>   plane--or a combination of both. In turn, in most modern submarines
>   these control surfaces are in cruciform. That is, the rise-dive
>   surfaces are generally in the same plane as the horizontal plane
>   through the centerline of the vessel, and the turning surfaces are in
>   the same plane as the vertical plane through the centerline. Thus, the
>   control surfaces are generally in the form of a Greek cross.
>
> In most cases the two rudder planes are yoked together, and the two
>   diving planes are yoked together. Because of this yoking, each pair of
>   control surfaces is operated by a single actuating rod. Thus, one rod
>   turns the ship, and the other rod causes the ship to rise or dive.
>
> It is known that arranging the control surfaces or planes of a
>   submarine in an X configuration has certain advantages. In this form,
>   the control surfaces are in the form of an X. Unlike cruciform
>   designs, X-stern designs utilize all four planes as part of any
>   maneuver. Therefore, an X-stern design enjoys more maneuvering force
>   per unit of control surface area than cruciform designs. X-stern ships
>   can be designed with smaller control surfaces while maintaining
>   maneuvering envelopes comparable to cruciform ships with larger
>   control surfaces. Smaller control surfaces obviously have less drag,
>   but may also be quieter--a very important factor today for a
>   submarine.
>
> The submarine USS ALBACORE had an X-stern configuration where the
>   opposite control surfaces were yoked together. Australian submarines
>   of the recent COLLINS class have X-stern configurations, but the
>   control surfaces are not yoked together and each of the four surfaces
>   has its own actuator. These are two examples of the current known
>   methods of actuating X-sterns. In both cases, the control system for
>   the operating rods is more complicated than that aboard a cruciform
>   ship. In a cruciform ship, if the helmsman wants to turn the ship, the
>   control system commands the rudder operating rod to extend or retract.
>   If a change in depth is required, the control system commands the
>   diving operating rod to extend or retract. In both X-stern designs,
>   the control system commands every operating rod to move in one
>   direction or the other, for any maneuver. Controlling these
>   coordinated operating rod movements is a complex task that can be
>   accomplished with a computer. However, manual coordination of the
>   operating rods, in the event of a computer casualty, is difficult. 
>   The proven X-rudder configuration was chosen for a
>   high manoeuvrability. The rudders are laid out in a way that they
>   press a preswirl on the propeller inflow which homogenizes the wake
>   flow field and increases the propeller efficiency on the one hand and
>   reduces the noise signature on the other hand. The propelling power is
>   provided by a Skewback propeller whose extremely low rotation speed
>   prevents cavity and which generates thrust silently even at high
>   speeds.

Answer (score 2):

×-form surfaces result in a shallower draft.  ×-form surfaces are more convenient for landing on the floor.  With +-form   the bottom fin which stick down below the bottom of the vehicle.

From what I've noticed, the littoral submarines have ×-form surfaces, because they are intended for shallow waters.

Answer (score 0):

Effectively none, the result is you can control up, down, left, right but with the x-form a combination of fins is necessary while with cross (second image) only a pair of fins is needed.

Comment: In terms of control of the submarine I agree with you, but I'm wondering about the flow of fluid over the different types of rudders & whether the X type might have a more complicated flow which might affect the amount of noise &/or the frequency of noise produced by the rear end of the submarine.

Comment: Then you need to update your original question with that information as people can’t guess what you want to ask...

Comment: First thought is the prop probably creates so much noise cf the fins...

Comment: X fits in the box better. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f8/Patriot_missile_launch_b.jpg/300px-Patriot_missile_launch_b.jpg

Comment: I disagree with your claim about "one pair."  A single pair out of  X-form is the same as a single pair of Cross-form, with the entire body rotated by $\frac{\pi}{4}$ .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft So that means descent at an angle instead of vertical, which means same depth but greater distance travelled...